# Java JfreeChart - how to make zooming in it is less?

Tags: java, zooming, jfreechart

The embedded function of `zoomInBoth` in Jfreechart too strongly zooming in. Whether it is possible to reduce an zooming level? I make my own `JButton zoomIn`

```
static ChartPanel chartPanel;
zoomIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            chartPanel.zoomInBoth(E, E);
    });
```

Edit of numbers in `zoomInBoth` changes nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the zooming factor using [setZoomInFactor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setZoomInFactor%28double%29) method on ChartPanel. The parameters in zoomInBoth specify the point where zooming happens.